# How to create multiple web socket event in jetty?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I am developing java web application & run on a Jetty Server that can have a number of people connect to the server by using web socket.
I am sending data from web socket to connected devices.(broadcast) 
Now I want to create multiple event in jetty such that data will send to particular user who is subscribe for that event.
How can I achieve this?Is it possible to create multiple event in jetty web socket?

Answer (score 0):

You have a pretty typical scenario for private + public communications.

A basic example exists as an [answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15649791/775715).

However, if you want private + public + groups, then you get into a pretty standard technology concept known as publish/subscribe.

There are many good frameworks out there to do the heavy lifting for publish/subscribe for you, and support websockets on Jetty.

Consider (a small selection):

- [Cometd](http://cometd.org/) - the core Jetty developers also work on this project.  multiple clients and protocols (websocket + various fallbacks to long polling, etc...) supported
- [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) - an open source publish/subscribe framework that supports Jetty.