# Jetty How to Create Custom WebSocket

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

Looking around online, I have found that the way to create a socket is to create a class with the @WebSocket annotation and use the desirable annotated methods for events. In order for this socket to be used, a socket handler is used like so:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletFactory;

import rsvp.RSVPSocket;

public class RSVPWebSocketHandler extends WebSocketHandler
{

    @Override
    public void configure ( WebSocketServletFactory factory )
    {
        factory.register( MySocket.class );
    }

}
```

My question is: if "MySocket" class has a constructor that has parameters, how can I make the factory invoke that one correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create socket from your servlet. For example:

```
@WebServlet(name = "MyWebSocketServlet", urlPatterns = {"/myurl"})
public class MyWebSocketServlet extends WebSocketServlet {
    private final static int IDLE_TIME = 60 * 1000;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
        factory.getPolicy().setIdleTimeout(IDLE_TIME);
        factory.setCreator(new CustomWebSocketCreator());
    }
}
```

And CustomWebSocketCreator:

```
public class CustomWebSocketCreator implements WebSocketCreator {

    @Override
    public Object createWebSocket(ServletUpgradeRequest req, ServletUpgradeResponse resp) {
        return new MySocket();
    }
}
```

More details:
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.1.5.v20140505/jetty-websocket-server-api.html

Answer (score 1):

According to [Jetty doc](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.2.5.v20141112/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/servlet/WebSocketCreator.html#createWebSocket(org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.ServletUpgradeRequest,%20org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.ServletUpgradeResponse)) you shall override `createWebSocket` method of your own *custom* derivation of the `WebSocketCreator` class (pass the instance of your creator to `configure`)

See also this answer [How do I access instantiated WebSockets in Jetty 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646213/how-do-i-access-instantiated-websockets-in-jetty-9)