# I have opened multiple websocket client data stream in jetty java with different api and secret calls , how do i close a particular session?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, jetty-9, java-websocket

In my current code i had a servlet from which if i create post to the servlet it will open a new websocket client , that mean 10 client connection each running for same purpose but with different api and secret , so i need to close particular session

I am using Jetty :: Websocket :: Client v9.4.48.v20220622

Please suggest , as i can get the session details but unable to use because it's not working with String data type . only in Session session it is working and i am unable to store session details anywhere else , as only in String data type i can save .

Whereas a is my API and b is my Secret Key ;

PS : Websocket connection is working fine to send expected data

```
class connector  {
    
    String a;
    String b;
    
    
    public void start() {

            WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
            MyWebSocket socket = new MyWebSocket();
            
            try {
                
                client.start();
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            URI destUri = null;
            try {
                destUri = new URI("wss://socket.delta.exchange");
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
            System.out.println("Connecting to: " + destUri);
            try {
                client.connect(socket, destUri, request);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                socket.awaitClose(3600, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                client.stop();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @WebSocket
        public class MyWebSocket {
        
            private final CountDownLatch closeLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

            @OnWebSocketConnect
            public void onConnect(Session session) throws IOException {
                
                session.getRemoteAddress();
                
                System.out.println("Connection opened");
                PingPong newObj = new PingPong();
                newObj.session = session;
                Authorization authMe = new Authorization();
                Identifier getSt = new Identifier();
                newObj.enableHeartBeat();
                System.out.println(session);
               
                
                session.getRemote().sendString(authMe.data(a, b));
               
            }

            @OnWebSocketMessage
            public void onMessage(String message) {
                
                MessageHandler objmsg = new  MessageHandler();
                objmsg.check();
                
                 System.out.println(
                            "Current Thread ID: "
                            + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                    
                System.out.println("Message from Server:  -- " + message);
            }
            
            @OnWebSocketClose
            public void onClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
                System.out.println("WebSocket Closed. Code:" + statusCode);
            }
            


            public boolean awaitClose(int duration, TimeUnit unit) 
                    throws InterruptedException {
                return this.closeLatch.await(duration, unit);
            }
        }
}
```

I want to do `session.close()` for a particular session details which i got from

```
session.getRemoteAddress().toString();


Session session ;
String sessionDetailSaved ;
```

i want to search for `sessionDetailSaved`  and compare with all the on running sessions and close it

Or else any other way i can close particular session with different method may be interrupting session thread but sure it will not completely close connection .

Maven Dependency i am using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>websocket-client</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.48.v20220622</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15649791/17650498 — is it what are you looking for?

Comment: here in chat if someone left the chat window it will close session as further it is not communicating . in my case client connection will remain open until  i fire a POST request with STOP trigger .

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Session.close()` will initiate a close handshake where the remote endpoint should reply with a response close frame, and once the close response has been received the WebSocket connection will be closed. You can send custom close status code and reason with `Session.close(int statusCode, String reason)`.

You also have the option to call `Session.disconnect()` which will do a hard close of the underlying connection without sending this close frame.

In regards to your code, it looks like you are never completing the `closeLatch` in the `OnWebSocketClose` method, so your `awaitClose` method will always timeout.

Also, if possible you should try to re-use the same `WebSocketClient` instance for multiple connections because it is a heavy weight object. It is expensive to create a new one for each request.